# Non-cacheable Javascript snippets using UI components?

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, full-page-cache, ecommerce-tracking

I'm asking this question as I'm unsure about the best way to proceed.

I've ported a module from Magento 1 to Magento 2, and it includes some Javascript tracking snippets that contain a small amount of dynamic data, e.g. an extra line or two if you've just added a product to your cart.

I'm concerned that the full page cache in Magento 2 will get in the way of the dynamic nature of some of these snippets.

Questions:

1. Do I need to worry about the FPC here?
2. Should I be using a UI component for this?
3. Would this be the recommended approach for implementing these kinds of things in Magento 2?

Comment: For caching on ur server r u using any other system or Magento Itself? https://www.sherodesigns.com/content-caching-dynamic-content-in-magento-2/ / https://fullpagecache.net/

Comment: Theoretical question. We are using OOB functionality, presume this means Varnish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do I need to worry about the FPC here?**

Yes, if you are using dynamic contents.

**Should I be using a UI component for this?**

It depends. UI component is an extended version of knockout js MVVM pattern. The main purpose of UI component is to add updates to DOM elements. Have a look at

```
app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js
app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html
```

If you do not want to add any updates to the DOM you do not need to use UI component.

Check how they have implemented GoogleTagManager without UI components.

```
app/code/Magento/GoogleTagManager/view/frontend/templates/js.phtml
```

Most of the data in the front end are observable. So if you want to track events like add to cart you can subscribe observable related object.

E.g

```
define([
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (customerData) {
    'use strict';
    function initialize() {
        var cartData = customerData.get('cart');
        cartData.subscribe(function (updatedCart) {
            // do what ever with updated cart
        }, this);
    }

    document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
        initialize();
    });
});
```

**Would this be the recommended approach for implementing these kinds of things in Magento 2?**

I think so. Have a look at the way Magento implemented the mini cart. They have stored data in local storage and bind to the DOM using observable. Check `app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js` how they store, retrieve and update data from/to local storage.

There is a plugin that can be used to debug knockout js context. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof